# Slow Macbook Pro Early 2008 Running on Mountain Lion (Possibly due to GPU Failing)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd, graphics, gpu

I have a Macbook Pro (Early 2008) running on Mountain Lion with a Samsung SSD. Just a few days ago i've noticed significant lag when switching desktops or using any intensive video program and generally the whole desktop experience feels really "heavy".

I run the AHT just today and i've got this error "4vdc/1/40000003" which is allegedly a problem with my video card and also after checking the GPU temparature, it's constantly on 78 celcius.

What should I do? Is it definitely an issue with the Graphics Card or The hard drive?

[image]

Comment: If you do not trust the AHT run it again to see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Yah this is one of those errors that likely mean a hardware failure and generally speaking the only way you are repairing a failure like this (unless you are into completely disassembling your Mac) is via an Apple Store or an AASP (Apple Authorized Service Provider).

Failing all the suggestions above you may need to (first: make a backup) make a Genius Bar appointment and let a tech that does this for a living run some diagnostics. I **believe** such diagnostics are free, if they can do them in-store.

If they can't do them in store they'll tell you and give you the cost. An AASP might be able to beat the price. you could call them with the Apple Genius Bar diagnostics for a ballpark estimate.

Unfortunately there is no great solution to this one. Unless you can afford something new...

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately not much we can do for you.

If you are a DIY you could save some and do it your self.

Here are some links for that.

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/9045/MBP+A1226+Logic+Board+last+resort+fix+for+nVidia+video+chip

https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/88614/Is+there+anyway+to+avoid+an+nVidia+8600+graphics+failure

or pick your correct model and look up.

Comment: lol. so what do i do? i just sit and wait till it fails?

Comment: You can do that or be proactive and repair it following above instructions.